# Genus of a Compact Riemann Surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

I was reading from Otto Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces, and he defined the genus of a surface in a way that does not reflect any geometric intuition.

Basically, we prove that $H^1(X,\mathcal{O})$, the first cohomology group with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}$, where $X$ is a compact Riemann surface, and $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions, is finite-dimensional, and we define that as the genus of the surface $X$.

On the other hand, the genus is the number of handles on the surface, that is, the maximum number of non-intersecting closed curves such that the surface remains connected.

It is clear how defining the genus in terms of curves actually gives us the number of handles on the surface, but it is totally unclear how the dimension of the first cohomology group actually captures that concept.

I would be grateful if someone can give me the connection.

Comment: It seems to me that your question pretty much captures the whole intuition. To say anything deeper is to delve into the proof of the theorem that the two notions of genus are equivalent. Are there particular aspects of the proof that you wish to understand more intuitively?

Comment: What I'm asking is that I have no idea how to move from the dimensionality of some cohomology of sheaves to something like the number of handles, or curves. I have no idea how to move between these two concepts, as cohomology of sheaves of holomorphic functions seems pretty far from any geometrical concept to be honest.

Comment: Well then I will re-emphasize what I said in my comment: There is a theorem which says that these two notions of genus are equivalent, so what you might try is to read and understand the proof of that theorem. Then you will see how to "move between those two concepts". I agree that the two notions seem pretty far apart, which makes the theorem all the more remarkable, and would make me all the more eager to read its proof in order to bridge that large gap.

Comment: Its proof seems pretty technical to be honest, and pretty long, with no geometric intuition. It builds up on too many things. However, can you tell me the name of that theorem which gives equivalence? Also, I will try to re-read everything again (It builds up on a lot of stuff to prove it) and see if I can connect from beginning to end to something geometrical.

Comment: Follow-up question: did you ever locate a good source/reference for this theorem?